# Автоперенос тегов

Tags: вёрстка, visual-studio-code

Добрый день уважаемые разработчики.
Столкнулся с проблемой автопереноса тегов при закрытии через TAB.
Тег закрывается в строчку.Как сделать так, чтоб тег закрывался на следующую строку с пробелом.(второй скрин) [image: нормальное закрытие тегов]
[image: закрытие тега]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При вводе тега через emmet, тег идет в строчку. Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб при написании тега через TAB, закрывающий тег переносился на 2 строки ниже, тобишь создавал пробел между тегами.